# about face detection system

Tags: face-detection

Some face detection system. Here are some of things I have known: opencv, dlib, stasm. So, is there any other open source face detection system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to train a machine learning algorithm that detects the faces from images or videos , you can check **YOLO**
https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet

Comment: I have tried YOLO, it's great! I also take a look at https://github.com/dannyblueliu/YOLO-version-2-Face-detection.Thank so much~

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is popular. But maybe you can try CCV (https://github.com/liuliu/ccv).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it later.

Answer (score 0):

Also good ones are 
Seeta https://github.com/seetaface/SeetaFaceEngine
Pico https://github.com/nenadmarkus/pico